# Listening to window events within Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-jsinterface

I'm loading a webpage within a WebView and trying to subscribe to JS events. As an example, let's say I'm looking for the window 'load' event.

I configure the webview in its `onFinishInflate`:

```
webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.addEventListener('load', function(){alert('loaded');})");
```

I assume this registration persists across page navigations and that it can be made before any page is actually loaded (due to being done on `window`).

When loading any url following that, such as `webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")`, no alert shows up.

I have also tried loading that javascript string as a url in the web view client's `onPageStarted` & `onPageFinished`. No difference.

Is it possible to subscribe to a web view's window events? Eventually, I plan on using the `@JavascriptInterface` pattern to call back into the native code when the JS event occurs. I would like to avoid having the web page itself know about the injected Java/JS object (having to verify the existence of this bridge object before calling a method on it seems sloppy– I find the event bus pattern cleaner here).